# how to generate doc for typescript enum type {[key]: value }?

Tags: typescript, enums, jsdoc, tsdoc

I am writing a logger service for nodeJS in Typescript. I have an enum as below:

```
enum LOG_TYPES {
  NONE = 0,
  ERROR = 1,
  WARN = 2,
  INFO = 3,
  DEBUG = 4,
}
```

then I have an setLogType function:

```
setLogType(type: LOG_TYPES) {
 this.logType = type
}
```

My problem is I don't know how to make docs for the `type` param.

[image: current behaviour]

My expectation is the recommendation would show like this

```
0                   NONE
1                   ERROR
2                   WARN
3                   INFO
4                   DEBUG
...
```

Comment: Use this. ```Logger.setLogType(LOG_TYPES.NONE) ```

Comment: Then I need to export LOG_TYPES and import it in another file, that is not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum LOG_TYPES {
  NONE = 0,
  ERROR = 1,
  WARN = 2,
  INFO = 3,
  DEBUG = 4,
}
setLogType(type: keyof typeof LOG_TYPES) {
 this.logType = type
}
```